# Delete rows starting with specific characters in a text file using Python

Tags: python

I have an annoying output file like this:

```
*** Warning: OpenMpAssembler::assemble_interior_facets is untested.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
Coloring mesh.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
Coloring mesh.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
Solving linear system of size 108360 x 108360 (PETSc Krylov solver).
Solving linear system of size 36120 x 36120 (PETSc Krylov solver).
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
   0/240 +0.000000e+00 -1.146247e-08 +0.000000e+00 +1.913417e-03 +0.000000e+00     +0.000000e+00
*** Warning: OpenMpAssembler::assemble_interior_facets is untested.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
Solving linear system of size 108360 x 108360 (PETSc Krylov solver).
Solving linear system of size 36120 x 36120 (PETSc Krylov solver).
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
   1/240 +5.000000e-05 -2.024630e-08 -3.666293e-08 +1.913417e-03 +1.073840e-10    +3.479053e-21
*** Warning: OpenMpAssembler::assemble_interior_facets is untested.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
Solving linear system of size 108360 x 108360 (PETSc Krylov solver).
Solving linear system of size 36120 x 36120 (PETSc Krylov solver).
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
*** Warning: Form::coloring does not properly consider form type.
   2/240 +1.000000e-04 -3.529024e-08 -3.825476e-08 +1.913417e-03 +1.077877e-10 +2.308941e-20
```

The list goes on, I just wanted to extract

```
0/240 +0.000000e+00 -1.146247e-08 +0.000000e+00 +1.913417e-03 +0.000000e+00 +0.000000e+00
1/240 +5.000000e-05 -2.024630e-08 -3.666293e-08 +1.913417e-03 +1.073840e-10 +3.479053e-21
2/240 +1.000000e-04 -3.529024e-08 -3.825476e-08 +1.913417e-03 +1.077877e-10 +2.308941e-20
```

How do I do it in Python? Basically I want to ignore lines starting with ***, Coloring and Solving

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Create another file without those lines or just iterate over it inside some procedure?

Comment: Amazing.  `re` answers are beating `startswith` 3 to 2 as I write this (I'm not counting the command-line `grep` answer as `re`).  Plus one for simply `in`.  And none of the `startswith` answers use the tuple parameter introduced in Python 2.5.

Answer (score 3):

```
f=open('annoying.txt','r')
input_stream=f.read()
output_stream=""
input_stream_lines=input_stream.split("\n")
for line in input_stream_lines:
    if "***" in line or "Solving" in line or "Coloring" in line:
            pass
    else:
            output_stream=output_stream+line+"\n"
g=open('output.txt','w')
g.write(output_stream)
```

Assuming that your text is in a file called annoying.txt, and output (filtered result) in a file output.txt

**EDIT**

The if condition may be changed to:

```
if line.startswith("***") or line.startswith("Solving") or line.startswith("Coloring"):
```

**EDIT2**

If newline is the separator, you may also do

```
input_stream_lines=f.readlines()
```

Comment: `startswith` is better to use than just checking for `'***' in line` because maybe the some significant line include some '*'s not at the beginning.

Comment: Agreed. But looking at what the OP wants, both approaches should work fine. startswith might also be better in terms of time as it won't need to check the entire line

Comment: Why do you read in the whole file as a single string and then split on the newlines yourself?  This is even worse than using `.readlines()` which two other answers have done.

Comment: Agreed it was not needed in this case and is slow, in some of the cases the separator may be a tab or some other character. So maybe to illustrate that maybe.

Answer (score 1):

The [`startswith`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method may help you:

> *str*.**startswith**(*prefix*[, *start*[, *end*]])
>   Return True if string starts  with the prefix, otherwise return False.
>   prefix can also be a tuple of
>   prefixes to look for. With optional start, test string beginning at
>   that position. With optional end, stop comparing string at that
>   position.

Following is a sample code that shows a loop through the lines of a text file, printing only those which don't start with "`***`" and "`Solving`":

```
for l in open("myfile.txt").readlines():
  if not l.startswith("***") and not l.startswith("Solving"): print(l)
```

Comment: What's good about this answer that it includes the documentation for `startswith`.  What's bad about this answer is that `.readlines()` is completely superfluous (and probably bad, because it forces reading the whole file into memory), and that despite including the documentation, there are two `startswith` invocations instead of a single one with a tuple argument. And the answer is not PEP-8 formatted, even though there is no compelling reason to avoid PEP 8 in this instance.

Comment: @JohnY: You're absolutely right: the code is neither elegant nor effective. It is just the more trivial working example, readable enough also for a beginner, that came to my mind.

Comment: I don't think using `readlines` is more trivial than **not** using `readlines`.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not (line.startswith("***") or line.startswith("Solving")):
            print line
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want a one-liner to filter this into a different file, just use grep:

```
grep -ve "^(Solving\|\*\*\*)" input.txt > output.txt
```

Alternatively, look into `startswith` as other answers have pointed out.

Comment: or `type file.txt | find /V /I "Solving" | find /V /I "*** "` in case you are on Windows ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import re
f = open('badfile.txt', 'r')
result = 0
for line in f.readlines():
    r = re.search(r'^\*\*\*|^Solving')
    if r:
        continue
    result += line + '\n'
print result
```

Comment: If you're going to use `re` instead of `startswith`, at least use `match` instead of `search`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like FEniCS output. You can suppress the unwanted messages by stating:

```
set_log_level(ERROR)
```

in your code.

Comment: I have done that, but the output text file still contains them :(

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

with open('log.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not re.match("^\*\*\*", line):
            print line,
```

Edit: Too Slow

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
import re
from itertools import ifilter

with open('/tmp/annoying.txt','r') as f:
     for line in ifilter(lambda x: re.match(r'\s+\d+',x),f):
         print line.strip()
```

Prints:

```
0/240 +0.000000e+00 -1.146247e-08 +0.000000e+00 +1.913417e-03 +0.000000e+00     +0.000000e+00
1/240 +5.000000e-05 -2.024630e-08 -3.666293e-08 +1.913417e-03 +1.073840e-10    +3.479053e-21
2/240 +1.000000e-04 -3.529024e-08 -3.825476e-08 +1.913417e-03 +1.077877e-10 +2.308941e-20
```